# Series' object has no attribute 'order'

Tags: python-3.6

My code is

```
disagreements = pivoted[pivoted.movie_id.isin(top_50.index)]["diff"]
disagreements.order().plot(kind="bar", figsize=[10,15])
```

Error is

```
Series' object has no attribute 'order'
currently trying this on spider,python3.6. anybody with a solution please
```

Answer (score 13):

Please check the used Pandas library version. If you are using the latest one, you can use sort_values() method. For details, you can refer  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
disagreements.sort_values().plot(kind="bar", figsize=[10,15])
```